IndentationError even if VSCode insert it automatically
I'm a beginner with Python and I started using VSCode to study it.
Until yesterday I had no problems writing code that requires indentation, it all worked fine, but now I keep getting the indentation error even if VSCode insert automatically the indentation when necessary.
For example the following code worked fine:
nomi=['A', 'B', 'C']
nomi
for nome in nomi: 
    print(nome)

But now the error I keep getting is the following one:
>>> for nome in nomi: 
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'for' statement on line 1

I get this specific error everytime I try to run a code with indentation, even if when I wrote it the first time it worked just fine.
I don't understand what changed and it seems I can't find any solution (I tried changing the settings for the indentation, but the error keeps showing up. Maybe I'm missing something in understanding the specific options about the issue).
Can someone help me please find a solution?

really hard to tell whats going on because you only shared the working version.

That is the version that worked before and now it doesn't work anymore. Could you please tell me what I should add to make the question more clear?

Your example has >>>> looks like you are in interactive python and that has nothing to do with vscode.   If you hit the enter on empty line that python repl did indent for you, you get that error. This is afaik a limitation of interactive python - when you hit enter without entering anything, python considers "un-indents" and you have empty for loop and thus, you get error that python was expecting a block ..
